# How to maintain scroll position when using HTML.ActionLink in MVC Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Approve", new {id = item.Id})">Approve</a>
```

This calls an Action method in my controller updates the approval status of the record and then:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

As expected, the page always refreshes to the top. Is there a way to maintain the scroll position to where I clicked the hyperlink. I have checked similar posts, but the ones I have seen referred to forms. Ultimately I will use JQuery/Ajax. However at present I want to see if there was a simple method that could be used like an HTML attribute.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name the anchor tag and refer to the name in the `href` using the hash notation:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Approve", new { id = item.Id })" id="@( item.Id )" name="@( item.Id )">Approve</a>
```

And then in your action method:

```
string redirectUrl =
    string.Format(
        "{0}#{1}",
        Url.Action("Index"),
        id);

return new RedirectResult(redirectUrl);
```

Just make sure your `id` is a value HTML `id` (nearly anything can be a valid `id` in HTML5, however rules apply for the naming of `ids` for earlier HTML versions).  If in doubt, prefix it with something like 'aid-' (approval id), etc. before using in the HTML.

Otherwise, like you've already identified, your best bet is to use an AJAX call to make the approval.  This way you stay exactly where you are on the page.

Comment: Should it be "name" or "id"?

Comment: I think it needs to be 'name'.

Comment: Actually it might be `id` or both.  If your `id` is dynamic then you just need to insert it into the `name` attribute, and then construct the hash bit in the action method similarly.  I'll update the answer.